# Global monthly searches versus results

Tags: seo, google-keyword-tool

I compiled a report with global monthly searches last week for my boss, regarding SEO (this is from Google AdWords). He, however, seems to want a report of the results for a specific keyword - is there a way to get this information?

Comment: When you say "results", do you mean that you would like to see a list of ads that are shown for that keyword?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, quoting from [Track your account performance](http://support.google.com/adwords/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=tips.html#track).

> Your account statistics are reported at the campaign, ad group, and
>   keyword or placement levels. They include clicks, impressions, CTR,
>   average CPC or CPM, cost, average position, conversion rate, and
>   cost-per-conversion

You should be able to use the segment button to achieve this see these two support articles:-

- [How do I customize the data in my tables and reports?](http://support.google.com/adwords/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=166377)
- [How do I create reports?](http://support.google.com/adwords/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=29175)

Quoting:-

> If available, click the Segment button in the toolbar above the data
>   table and select the level of detail you'd like to apply to the data
>   in your table.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Indeed there. Head over to the Google Keyword Tool. Select your search as "Exact" search, and then key in your keywords. You should be able to generate the report for your specific keywords.